# Event handlers in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, events, handler

When I try to create an event handler eg. button click in c#, if I write the code manually in code behind class, the event handler won't be called; Whereas if I double click the button on the form and the VS auto generates the event, it will work perfectly. What is the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: there is a `Designer.cs` file which contains the events details of every click that is why it wouldn't call when you write code manually..

Comment: "the event handler won't be called" - show your event subscription code. Manual subscriptions should work as well, as ones made via form designer. Also, what GUI framework do you mean?

Comment: Hi Dennis, I meant windows form applications...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `Form.Designer.cs` file that hooks up the events for each individual form (each form has it's own designer file).

Open that and you'll find lines like:

```
button1.Click += button1_Click;
```

..etc.

As below:

[image: Designer file]

[image: Click wiring]

Comment: This is not an answer. OP asks, why his manual event subscription doesn't work.

Comment: @Dennis That's odd, because I read it as "how does this magic event handling happen". Also, it has been accepted by the OP.

Comment: I see, this is exactly what happens when you delete an event handler in your code behind and it gives you an error to delete the related code from Designer.cs. Thanks Simon and Rahul.

Answer (score 0):

Your file isnt able to know that the event handler is to be linked to the function you have created.

If you want to link manually, click on the button once, and in the top section of the properties window, you'll see a lightning symbol(events). Click on that, and scroll down to the click event, and over there, add your function.